# Combing 2 IF statements

Tags: php

I need to state that if a score is above 21 and the month nam is'whatever' then $month = '3'

```
if(strpos($data->form->name, 'april') !== false) && ($data->data->score * 1) >= 21 &&$x <= 41){
  $amonth = "3";
} 
elseif(($data->data->score * 1) >= 0 && ($data->data->score * 1) < 21){
  $month = "0";
}
```

Comment: So? what does your current code do? what doesn't work?

Comment: it will be easy to understand, if you share the result of `print_r($data)`

Comment: You need to add brackets around the operands you try to combine using the logical `&&` operator. Reason is the binding rules you violate or at least you apparently ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be like

```
if(strpos($data->form->name, 'april') !== false && ($data->data->score * 1) >= 21 && $x <= 41){
  $amonth = "3";
} elseif(($data->data->score * 1) >= 0 && ($data->data->score * 1) < 21){
$month = "0";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first line is written the wrong way, you miss some `()`

Use this :

```
if((strpos($data->form->name, 'april') != false) && (($data->data->score * 1) >= 21 &&$x <= 41)){
```

**Update:** Sorry, I've missed a `&&`.

It must be this to give the right result:

```
if((strpos($data->form->name, 'april') != false) && (($data->data->score * 1) >= 21)  && ($x <= 41)){
```

Only thing I can think of since your question isn't really clear.